# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception thrown

Tags: java, exception

```
public Pasient[] finnPasient(String dato)
{
    int j = 0;
    Pasient[] p = new Pasient[j];

    for(int i = 0; i < pasienter.length; i++)
    {
        if(pasienter[i] != null && pasienter[i].getFødselsdato().equals(dato))
        {
            p[j] = pasienter[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    if(j == 0)
        return null;

    else
        return p;
}
```

that is my method. I think I know what's wrong, but I am not sure how to fix it. I think that the arraylength does not update while the loop is running. Pasienter.length is always 100 for my tests. Ask me if you need any more info to respond, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int j = 0;
Pasient[] p = new Pasient[j];
```

`j` is 0, `p` has no elements at all, so the first element which is at index 0, is out of bounds, this probably happens at the line:

```
p[j] = pasienter[i];
  ↑
```

When you write `j++`, this **doesn't** enlarge the array that you've already created. Remember, array's size cannot be changed.

Since you don't know how long should the array be, I advise you to read about [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and do something like:

```
ArrayList<Pasient> p = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then,

```
p.add(pasienter[i]);
```

Comment: j++;
p[j] = pasienter[i];

I tried this as well, but it makes no difference

Comment: @Adrian What does this mean?

Comment: I should add that I want to return an array exactly the size of the amount of objects which fits the terms in the if-sentance.

Comment: There is no way around without using ArrayList? I am working with a specific examexample which does not allow for it. I know the largest possible number of objects, which if I am allowed to use that number, makes the method work perfectly right away

Comment: @Adrian There is, you can set the initial value to be the same as `pasienter`. According to your code, that should be enough and you'll never exceed the limits.